# Node.js Need to reformat console format

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am making a discord bot, and needed to use google sheets api for the bot
the google api response in console is not formatted correctly so i have to reformat the response.
it is a leaderboard so i hope that i can format it so it will make the first line rank, the second flag, third player ect.
this is how it formats it;

```js
[
  [
    '1',
    '',
    'person',
    '172',
    'levels',
    'discord',
    'levels',
    'levels',
    'levels'
  ],
  [
    '2',
    '',
    'person',
    '154',
    'levels',
    'discord',
    'levels',
    'None',
    'None'
  ],
```

here is how i need to be formatted;

```js
Repsponse {
  Rank: 1,
  flag:  ,
  Player: person,
  Points: 172,
  Levels: levels,
  Discord: discord,
      ],
      [
  Rank: 2,
  flag:  ,
  Player: person,
  Points: 154,
  Levels: levels,
  Discord: discord,
      ],
```

Hope that makes sense
thank you

Answer (score 0):

hello i was analyzing your problem try with the map function to transform the result

```
let response = {example:'value',example2:'value2'}
let response = [Object.keys(response).map(key => response[key])]
```

Comment: I need to redo the question because there is some things that arn't right